# What is this tree with green spherical fruit?

Tags: identification, trees, fruit-trees

I have searched everywhere and cannot seem to identify the type of tree this is.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is it located?

Comment: Charleston, South Carolina

Comment: It looks like a fig of some kind... the leaves are close to those of a [sacred fig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_fig), but it doesn't have the long, thin pointy end and it grows outside your region. My bet's on something closely related

Comment: My guess is a quince. Do you know what colour the fruit turns when ripe? Can you cut one in half and show what it looks like? Is it hard on the inside? These questions will go a long way to identifying the plant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's actually a [Tung tree](http://plants.ifas.ufl.edu/node/31).

Comment: Ha, yeah it is, don't listen to me, erasing my answer so no one gets sick trying to choke down one of those fruit.